# Is points to route still available in QGIS 3.4?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, point, network-analyst, route

I need to do the same thing as the [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/338052/routing-consecutive-set-of-points-on-network) here as I need to create polylines based on given points with sequence attribute, and networks, but I cannot find the tool in toolbox:
[image: network analysis in QGIS3.4]

[image: point data and network data]
my point data and network data

Is function `points to route` still available in QGIS 3.4?

Comment: I think you need to download it from https://github.com/anitagraser/QGIS-Processing-tools/blob/master/1.1/scripts/points_to_route.py